# WPF ScrollViewer's ViewportWidth is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, scrollviewer

I have a scrollviewer that I want to scroll to the right when the edge is reached. I am detecting the mouse position and comparing it to the scrollviewer's `ViewportWidth`. It works at first, when dragging to the edge it will scroll. However, once I let go, and try again, or if I hold on to the mouse and move back into the scrollviewer, it will keep going.

What I've noticed is that whatever width it is at initially (the first time I reach the edge), it seems to think that the `ViewportWidth` is still the same, even if I have scrolled. So it will scroll no matter what once it reaches that specific width.

Is there a way I can get `ViewportWidth` to update each time I scroll? I tried putting `UpdateLayout` in the function after changing the offset but it did not work. The goal here is so that the width updates continually, so that I can check if the edge of the viewport has changed.

Comment: I would have thought the viewport size stays the same unless you've resized the ScrollViewer. Do you need to use the ContentHorizontalOffset in your calculation?

Comment: Well, I was under the impression the ViewportWidth property specified the width that is currently viewable, so I guessed that it would constantly change if you are scrolling, since the viewable content changes. I considered using ContentHorizontalOffset but even with the info online I couldn't tell what it was. Ideally I would need the width of whatever content is viewable inside the scrollviewer so that I can compare the mouse position and scroll accordingly.

Comment: ViewportWidth is the currently viewable width, but as you scroll to the right and more content appears, the total visible width stays the same, as the left side of the content disappears. The ContentHorizontalOffset is the width of the content which is not visible due to being scrolled off the left of the view.  I would have expected you to use ViewportWidth for what you are doing but I'm not sure why you'd expect it change unless the ScrollViewer changed size, so I think your bug is somewhere else.

Comment: Tested this, works fine for me with a timer and comparing the mouse to the Viewport Width/Height.  Without code I don't think I could guess where your issue is.

Comment: Are you manually calculating the offset and calling `ScrollToHorizontal/VerticalOffset(offset)`, or are you binding to offsets?  Have you tried using `LineRight()` and `LineLeft()` at all?  Instead of calling `UpdateLayout` try calling `InvalidateScrollInfo()`.

Comment: @NETscape for now I am just calculating the offset as `ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset+2` just to test. I tried `LineRight/LineLeft` and those worked fine but my issue is that I only want to scroll when the edge is neared, not at a specific width as ViewportWidth gives me. I will try `InvalidateScrollInfo()` but what James Barrass said makes sense, the ViewportWidth is just the total width and it's a fixed value i guess. What I need is to detect when the edge of the ScrollViewer is reached, no matter the current scroll position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue by combining `ViewportWidth` with `HorizontalOffset`. Adding them, then comparing pt.X to it gave me the exact area between the Viewport and the overflow, allowing me to scroll.